# PL/SQL block query - Displaying total, Max, Min and Avg

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to PL/SQL and need to figure out the below question.. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with the query, so that I can get an idea of the question make up.

I want to create a new anonymous PL/SQL block that will displays the total number of employees in a company,their max, min and average salary with their average sal rounded to a whole number.

Is this correct?

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(salary),0) 'Maximum',  
ROUND(MIN(salary),0) 'Minimum',  
ROUND(SUM(salary),0) 'Sum',  
ROUND(AVG(salary),0) 'Average'  
FROM employees;
```

PL/SQL confuses me

Comment: That looks almost correct. Column names can be given either without any quotes at all, OR with DOUBLE quotes, such as "Sum". It is also best not to use reserved keywords like Sum as column names; best to use column names like Max_salary, Min_salary, Total_salary and Average_salary. And the second argument, 0, to `round()` is not needed, since 0 is the default anyway; you could simplify to `round(min(salary))` (and, if all salaries are integers to begin with, then only the average needs rounding - the others will be integers already). Overall it looks good. What's this got to do with PL/SQL?

Comment: It's not correct.  Nothing in your query returns the number or employees.  Also, if you ran that code, it would probably throw an error because of the single quotes around the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with quotes: in column aliases, you only can use `"`, if you need, or simply define the aliases with no quotes at all; the difference is, for example:

```
SQL> SELECT count(employee_id) as "Number of employees", -- double quotes: this alias will keep the case of my string and have spaces
  2  ROUND(MAX(salary),0) "Maximum",
  3  ROUND(MIN(salary),0) "Minimum",
  4  ROUND(SUM(salary),0) Sum, -- no quotes: this will be in UPPERCASE and you can have no spaces
  5  ROUND(AVG(salary),0) Average
  6  FROM employees;

Number of employees    Maximum    Minimum        SUM    AVERAGE
------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                107      24000       2100     691416       6462
```

Besides, to be precise, this is a SQL query, while the following is a PL/SQL block:

```
declare
    vCount number;
    vMax number;
    vMin number;
    vSum number;
    vAvg number;
begin  
    SELECT count(employee_id) as "Number of employees", 
    ROUND(MAX(salary),0) "Maximum",
    ROUND(MIN(salary),0) "Minimum",
    ROUND(SUM(salary),0) Sum, 
    ROUND(AVG(salary),0) -- you need no aliases here
    into vCount,
         vMax,
         vMin,
         vSum,
         vAvg
    FROM employees;
    --
    dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || vCount || ' - ' || 
                            'Max: ' || vMax || ' - ' ||
                            'Min: ' || vMin || ' - ' ||
                            'Sum: ' || vSum || ' - ' ||
                            'Avg: ' || vAvg);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

The question isn't 100% clear, but you say you need this by company, and that you also need to number of employee per company? I am guessing your table contains a field like nCompanyID?

You'd then have:

```
SELECT
    nCompanyID as Company -- I don't know if you have an ID or a string for it...
    COUNT(*) as nbEmployees,
    ROUND(MAX(salary),0) as MaximumSalary,
    ROUND(MIN(salary),0) as MinimumSalary,
    ROUND(SUM(salary),0) as TotalSalary,
    ROUND(AVG(salary),0) as AverageSalary
FROM employees
GROUP BY nCompanyID;
```

Note this is in MS SQL Server, but I'm sure oracle's SQL has pretty much the same syntax for this kind of things.

Comment: If you read the comments on the original question, you will see that you propagated one of the main issues: column aliases need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Except this is wrong. Single quotes work perfectly well... Can you please not downvote people when you have no clue about what you are saying? I'm trying to raise my reputation here...

Comment: I took that advice directly from a thread on Oracle'S website.

Also, let's say that thread was wrong. I clearly stated that was for MS SQL Server and that it might need some adjustments for Oracle. I'm still the only guy that actually tried to help by telling him how to add the nbEmployees and the group by companies...

Comment: I'm sorry that you misunderstood the thread you were reading, but this most definitely doesn't work. Posting an incorrect answer merits a down vote in my opinion, especially where the real answer was already given in comments.

Comment: How did I misunderstand the thread? I replied first to everything,  but I didn't corrected the quotes, because a thread on the ORACLE's boards confirmed me the single quotes work! If that thread was wrong, fine. But a simple edit could have solved everything. The other guy's answer is 10x more complicated for absolutely nothing.

Anyways, you know what? I'm not gonna try to help no more. Screw that. I was trying to help, but from now on, I don'T give a darn about other people. I'll keep using stack for getting answers, but I'm not going to help people if it ends up costing me...

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte - do you have a link to where you read that single quotes can be used for column names or aliases in Oracle? That is 100% wrong, but if you read that somewhere, perhaps we need to contact Oracle to correct the info they have there.

Comment: Don't remember how I searched for it, but my entire point is that instead of downvoting the guy that tries to help, and solves 95% of the problem, a simple comment or Edit to correct the issue would have been more professional, nicer, and all in all more logic... Downvoting rules out the answer for OP, while my answer is the most simple and clear on here...

Comment: I'm trying to raise my rep to be able to help (comments, legit votes, etc). I don't really want to help anymore. Not gonna help if it ends up costing me! I'll keep my help to myself. Don't feel like being looked down like that! If people can't be appreciative of the help I'm trying to give, I'm simply not going to help!